# How Do I transfer A Video Timeline From A PSD File To Other PSD Files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm in need of help! I'm currently a junior art student that is working on some animations assignments in Photoshop and ran into a problem. I have made video timelines in separate PSD files and wanted to merge them into a single PSD file. As I tried to copy and paste them into a single PSD file, the placements are not aligned and the animations became weird (not in place). I tried many methods and somehow it's not working. If any of you know how to solve it, please comment below. Your help is very much appreciated. TvT

Comment: You can try asking this on https://video.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works with video timelines but in general, when you want to paste something and keep the position, you need to use Paste in place (Ctrl+Shift+V).

For example if you cut something out of a picture and you want that thing on a new layer but you also want it to remain at the same position, you cut and then press Ctrl+Shift+V.